# wordpress cannot access admin section and website as theme does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

I am facing two challenges on this site as I was uploading a photo, it ended up crashing or something.

[The website URL is chandariaproperties.com. The front end is showing the below. I removed the plugins, reset .htaccess. flushed my cookies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdv49.png)

The wp-admin is showing as below

[I tried changing the site URL and also .htaccess still no nope. I really no other other idea on how to go about it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPKYh.png)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a case of the activated theme not existing then you can change it in the database.

You need to change the three rows in the options table that have the following value in the option_name field.

1. template – the “Theme Name” as defined in style.css
2. current_theme - the name of your theme folder
3. stylesheet – the name of your theme folder